# projectRaster results in different output when projecting with its own crs

Tags: r, gis, raster, map-projections

For a function I want to reproject a raster input - itself the output after using crop and mask - using a user set CRS. I thought that projecting with the existing crs would do nothing and simply return the input raster. To my surprise this was not the case. Below a reproducible example

Create dummy raster:

```
library(raster)

# Download country polygin, in this case Malawi
mwi <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "MWI", level = 0)

# Create dummy raster
grid <- raster::raster() # 1 degree raster
grid <- raster::disaggregate(grid, fact = 12) # 5 arcmin
grid <- raster::crop(grid, mwi)
values(grid) <- rep(1, ncell(grid)) # Set a value

# The input raster with dimensions 94,39,3666
grid <- raster::mask(grid, mwi)
plot(grid)
grid

# Reproject the raster using its own crs. I use ngb as it is a categorical variable.
# This raster has dimensions 102, 47, 4794 so it seems a lot of white space (NA) is added.
own_crs <- crs(grid)
grid_reproj <- raster::projectRaster(grid, crs = own_crs, method = "ngb")
plot(grid_reproj)
grid_reproj

# To remove the white space I use trim
# This results in a waster with dimensions 93, 39, 3627
grid_trim <- raster::trim(grid_reproj)
plot(grid_trim)
grid_trim

# I also decided to compare the maps visually with mapview
library(mapview)

# There seems to be a trim function in mapview which I set to FALSE
# Also use the browser for easy viewing
options(viewer = NULL)
mapviewOptions(trim = FALSE)
mapviewGetOption("trim")
mapview(grid, col.regions = "green", legend = F) +
  mapview(grid_reproj, col.regions = "red", legend = F) +
  mapview(grid_trim, col.regions = "blue", legend = F)
```

Comparing the maps I observe two things:

(1) grid and grid_trim are nearly identical apart from a single grid cell
on top. Perhaps this is due to rounding,

(2) grid_reproj has a much larger dimensions and different extent. It also
seems as if the map is slightly shifted in comparison to the other maps. This
is corrected by trim, so I assume that these are in fact NA cells and the difference might be
related how mapview displays the maps.

Hence, my main question is, what is happening when rasterProject projects with
the same extent? And why does the result differ, even after trim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To project raster data the *right* way you must supply another Raster* object, and not a only crs.

If you supply a crs, a new extent is computed, a bit larger than what is expected to be needed to avoid loosing data. Of course in this odd case where the crs is actually the same it would make sense to return the input unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the explanation. This certainly clarifies. Perhaps you can update the documentation of projectRaster to reflect this as it currently reads: "You can do this by providing the new projection as a single argument in which case the function sets the extent and resolution of the new object". Hence it suggest that one can use only the CRS argument and in fact, I have read in tutorials that recommendations to use it in this way to simply reproject a raster.